# speed changing for knives (obstacles) in pygame not working

Tags: python, performance, pygame

I'm currently making a game in python (`pygame`).
I have a function called `obstacle_movement` which moves my obstacles

```
#change of speed for the knives as game progresses
changeofspeed = 0

def obstacle_movement(obstacle_list):
    if obstacle_list:
        for obstacle_rect in obstacle_list:
            changeofspeed += 0.001
            obstacle_rect.y -= changeofspeed

            if obstacle_rect.x == 40:
                screen.blit(butcher_knife_surf,obstacle_rect)
            elif obstacle_rect.x == 520:
                screen.blit(knife_surf,obstacle_rect)

        obstacle_list = [obstacle for obstacle in obstacle_list if obstacle.y > -100]
        
        return obstacle_list 
    else: 
        return []
```

so, I implement a variable called `changeofspeed` but it gives an error

```
pygame 2.5.1 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.11.6)
 File "c:\Users\akhil\OneDrive\Desktop\Don't Get Sliced!\game.py", line 11, in obstacle_movement
for obstacle_rect in obstacle_list:
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'changeofspeed' where it is not associated with a value
```

fyi these functions are placed in the while True loop

Comment: inside function you have to use `global changeofspeed` to inform function that you want to assign new value to external variable. If you don't do this then it try to find local variable `changeofspeed`.

Comment: Or you should send it as argument `def obstacle_movement(obstacle_list, changeofspeed):` and `return obstacle_list, changeofspeed` and `return [], changeofspeed `

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should write it as answer because it should be basic knowledge.
And it has nothing to do with `pygame`.

---

If you change global/external variable `changeofspeed` inside function then you have to use `global changeofspeed` to inform function that you want to assign new value to external variable.

```
def obstacle_movement(obstacle_list):
    global changeofspeed

    # ... rest ...
```

---

Or you should send `changeofspeed` to function

```
def obstacle_movement(obstacle_list, changeofspeed):

    # ... rest ...

       return obstacle_list, changeofspeed
    else:
       return [], changeofspeed
```

and use it as

```
items, changeofspeed = obstacle_movement(items, changeofspeed)
```